# Redirect any link within a folder to a particluar page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using htaccess how do I redirect all requests to links with a folder, eg:

```
www.domain.co.uk/ap-products/functionaltraining/‎
www.domain.co.uk/ap-products/freeweights/olympic-plates.html‎
```

to:

```
www.domain.co.uk/products
```

Comment: Are all the URLs to be redirected in the same subfolder "al-products", or are we talking about a lot of different, undefined subfolders like www.domain.co.uk/fol1/ www.domain.co.uk/another-folder/ www.domain.co.uk/folder2/, etc.?

Comment: I just want to redirect any access to /ap-products/ and any page within it to /products/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect /ap-products and any subfolder of /ap-products/ to exactly /products, use the following htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ap-products
RewriteRule ^.*$ /products [R=302,L]
```

If you want to keep the request after /ap-products and attach it to /products, use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ap-products
RewriteRule ^ap-products/(.*)$ /products/$1 [R=302,L]
```

It will redirect /ap-products/product1 to /products/product1 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in your `/ap-products/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ap-products/

RewriteRule ^ /products [L]
```